# WDM device removal in PnP driver

Tags: windows, driver, wdm, plug-and-play

I have question about device removal.

When we want to notify PnP manager that device has disappeared we call `IoInvalidateDeviceRelations` with `BusRelations`. After that OS will send `IRP_MN_QUERY_DEVICE_RELATIONS` request with `BusRelations`. In this request handler we will exclude device from array and will do another necessary job to "disconnect" it from bus, also we will set `RemovePending` flag in its device extension.

I don't understand how to deal with incoming IO requests to the device after it becomes "remove pending" and before OS sends `IRP_MN_REMOVE_DEVICE` request. Should we check `RemovePending` flag and return `STATUS_DEVICE_DOES_NOT_EXIST` or should we proceed as usual?

Now imagine that `IRP_MN_REMOVE_DEVICE` request has finally arrived. MSDN says that we must call `IoReleaseRemoveLockAndWait` that releases the current acquisition of remove lock, prevents subsequent acquisitions and waits while existing acquisitions are released. So it forces us to always acquire remove lock inside PnP request handler with `IoAcquireRemoveLock`; and release it with `IoReleaseRemoveLockAndWait` for `IRP_MN_REMOVE_DEVICE` or with `IoReleaseRemoveLock` for another minor codes.

I don't understand why we need to acquire remove lock inside PnP request handler? In my understanding we need to acquire remove lock only for pending irp and release it when such irp is completed. So Windows folks could provide us with `IoWaitForExistingRemoveLocks` routine instead of `IoReleaseRemoveLockAndWait`.

Sorry if it's kinda messy, I just can't figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After that OS will send `IRP_MN_QUERY_DEVICE_RELATIONS` request with
>   `BusRelations`. In this request handler we will exclude device from
>   array and will do another necessary job to "disconnect" it from bus,
>   also we will set `RemovePending` flag in its device extension.

here need only exclude device from array and set `RemovePending` flag in its device extension. but do another necessary job to "disconnect" it from bus - need do only when you process `IRP_MN_REMOVE_DEVICE` (after device was not included in the bus driver's most recent response to an `IRP_MN_QUERY_DEVICE_RELATIONS` request for `BusRelations` - or in another words - when `RemovePending` flag in its device extension)

> how to deal with incoming IO requests to the device after it becomes
>   "remove pending" and before OS sends `IRP_MN_REMOVE_DEVICE` request.
>   Should we check `RemovePending` flag and return
>   `STATUS_DEVICE_DOES_NOT_EXIST` or should we proceed as usual?

i think possible both behavior - you can process it as usual and can return `STATUS_DEVICE_DOES_NOT_EXIST` too. and assume next situation - you get some IO request in concurrent with removal device process. when you check  `RemovePending` flag - it yet not set. and you begin process request "as usual". but just after you check `RemovePending` flag inside IO request you can set it while handling `IRP_MN_QUERY_DEVICE_RELATIONS` request with `BusRelations`. and this situation direct related to sense using [Remove Locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/using-remove-locks) **or** [Run-Down Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/run-down-protection).

we really can use Run-Down Protection instead Remove Locks almost in same way and exactly in same places and for same reason as Remove Locks. and i think Run-Down Protection api (more new compare remove locks) - better design and better for use (however different is minimal)

> I don't understand why we need to acquire remove lock inside PnP
>   request handler?

first of all note that about remove lock said only in [Removing a Device in a Function Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/removing-a-device-in-a-function-driver). you how i understand have not function, but bus driver- so [Removing a Device in a Bus Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/removing-a-device-in-a-bus-driver) more suitable for you. and in documentation for [Removing a Device in a Function Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/removing-a-device-in-a-function-driver) exist **serious error** - advice first call [`IoReleaseRemoveLockAndWait`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549567(v=vs.85).aspx) at point **4** - **before** point **8** - Pass the `IRP_MN_REMOVE_DEVICE` request down to the next driver. but correct must be

> driver should call `IoReleaseRemoveLockAndWait` **after** it passes
>   the `IRP_MN_REMOVE_DEVICE` request to the next-lower driver, and
>   before it releases memory, calls `IoDetachDevice`, or calls
>   `IoDeleteDevice`.

this is correct and stated in [Using Remove Locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/using-remove-locks) and [IoReleaseRemoveLockAndWait](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549567(v=vs.85).aspx). funny that in old msdn versions was

> call `IoReleaseRemoveLockAndWait` **before** it passes..

but now this is fixed. why after ? because next-lower driver can pending some IRPs (on which we call `IoAcquireRemoveLock` or `ExAcquireRundownProtection`) and complete it only when got `IRP_MN_REMOVE_DEVICE` and our driver call `IoReleaseRemoveLock` or `ExReleaseRundownProtection` only when this IRP will be completed. as result if call `IoReleaseRemoveLockAndWait` or `ExWaitForRundownProtectionRelease` **before** passes the remove IRP to the next-lower driver - we can wait here forever - next-lower driver can not complete some IRP (until not got remove request) and we not release remove lock or rundown protection.

so for what we need remove locks or rundown protection ? because we can got `IRP_MN_REMOVE_DEVICE` in concurrent with another IO requests. and this IO requests can **use** some resources on device. from another sized when we process `IRP_MN_REMOVE_DEVICE` we **destroy** this resources. what be if we will use some resource in IO request after he will be destroyed in `IRP_MN_REMOVE_DEVICE` ? think not need answer. for prevent this and exist removal locks or rundown protection. before use any resource (which will be destroyed in remove) need call `IoAcquireRemoveLock` or `ExAcquireRundownProtection` and use it only if ok status returned. after we finish use resource call `IoReleaseRemoveLock` or `ExReleaseRundownProtection`. and in `IRP_MN_REMOVE_DEVICE` we call `IoReleaseRemoveLockAndWait` or `ExWaitForRundownProtectionRelease`. after this call is returned - we can be sure that nobody use our resources and never will be used more (calls to `IoAcquireRemoveLock` or `ExAcquireRundownProtection` return error status (false)). at this point we can safe begin destroy resources: releases memory (etc), calls `IoDetachDevice`,  `IoDeleteDevice`.

the pointer to the next-lower device - this is also resource, which we **use** in process IO request and **destroy** in `IRP_MN_REMOVE_DEVICE` (by call `IoDetachDevice`). really are correct call `IofCallDriver(_nextDeviceObject, Irp);` (while process some IO request) **after** call `IoDetachDevice(_nextDeviceObject);` (inside `IRP_MN_REMOVE_DEVICE`) ? because this removal locks (or i use yourself rundown-protection here ) always used in functions and filter drivers. for bus driver, where we usually have not pointer to the next-lower device (*PDO* not attached to another device, when *FDO* attached to *PDO* and filter always attached to something) - may be not need locks (or rundown protection at all). this is depend - are exist another resources - used and destroyed (on removal).

and for bus devices - usual situation when  we got `IRP_MN_REMOVE_DEVICE` 2 time - first before device marked as `RemovePending` - so we go to point 4. and after device marked as `RemovePending` (so  device was not included in the bus driver's most recent response to an IRP_MN_QUERY_DEVICE_RELATIONS request for BusRelations) we finally destroy resources and call `IoDeleteDevice`

Comment: @RbMmThank you for the answer, it is very clearly. So the idea is to protect resources (device object, its extension, etc) from being freed while we are processing another request. The thing that I still dont understand: we store remove lock in the device extension, so to acquire it we need to access this extension. Where is the guarantee that by the time we access it the call to IoDeleteDevice was not already executed (so device object and its extension are freed)?

Comment: @new_user - if somebody send IO request to us - he must have pointer to DeviceObject and must be sure that he have reference to it (DeviceObject). so DeviceObject and DeviceExtension is valid (as memory storage). but state of DeviceObject - already another question - heve reference to object - not gurantee it state. only memory validity. and rundown protection used for protect part of object which can be destroyed **before** object itself will be destroyed.

Comment: @new_user - for example i allocate memory buffer `devext->Buf` on start device. and io requests used this `Buf`. somebody have pointer with reference to my device (or even file opened on it) and send ioctl to it. the device object itself will be valid(as memory storage) until sender not release own reference(close file). even if we call `IoDeleteDevice` (memory will be freeded after last reference go to 0). but if we got remove request in concurent woth this ioctl and will not use rundown protection - we can free `Buf` until ioctl use it.

Comment: the call `ExWaitForRundownProtectionRelease` give next - we wait if somebody use `Buf` at this time. and at once disable more use `Buf`. after this we can safe free `Buf`

Comment: @RbMmGreat, thank you. Sorry if I get too curious, I still have one question. I have DispatchDeviceControl, DispatchCleanup, DispatchClose handlers. These requests are sent to bus FDO from user mode, in other words we have file opened on bus FDO (so validity of bus FDO and its extension as memory storage is guaranteed), but we need to access child PDO to complete the request (we use notion of device namespace):

ChildPDO = (DEVICE_OBJECT*)((IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp))->FileObject->FsContext);

Comment: @RbMmI fear that we will receive IRP_MN_REMOVE_DEVICE request while processing one of the aforementioned requests. Reference counter for child PDO will drop to zero and memory will be freed. I feel we need to create additional reference for child PDO and release it inside DispatchClose request handler, but I am not sure.

Comment: I think I understand. OS will increment reference counter on a given file object before it calls DispatchDeviceControl or DispatchCleaunup; OS will decrement reference counter on a given file object when we complete request. It means that DispatchDeviceControl and DispatchCleaunup can run concurrently, but DispatchClose cannot, we will get it only after we complete all another requests. Hence we are safe to release reference to child PDO in DispatchClose, while PnP manager will have its own reference.

Comment: in general you `FDO` maintain list of childs `PDO` and you remove `PDO` from list or when user close associated fileobject (you mark this pdo and call `IoInvalidateDeviceRelations`) or user select eject device. in this case first your pdo received `IRP_MN_REMOVE_DEVICE` (you not destroy it here because it enumerated, only mark. then fdo receive `BusRelations` - you remove this pdo from list and free reference on it. and then you fdo second time got `IRP_MN_REMOVE_DEVICE` - here you already delete it, because it not enumerated. i have exactly the same soft.

Comment: @new_user you need protect access to pdo (via `FileObject->FsContext`) say by AcquirePushLockShared/ReleasePushLock on FDO. also AcquirePushLockShared/ReleasePushLock used when handle BusRelations.

Comment: so on ioctl when you need access `PDO`  (as `FileObject->FsContext` pointer) you enter some critsec - look are this stil not 0, and if yes - addref (if need send io to it) or mar as remove pending(on close or cleanup) and exit crit sec. then send request and release. or call `InvalidateDeviceRelations`. in handle `BusRelations` - you also enter the same critsec fro syncronize access to pdo list with user mode ioctls. this is separate from use rundown protection on PDO. so one protection on PDO (if need) another on `FDO`. this is most thin points. hard describe all on pure english here. :)

Comment: @RbMmBy "select eject device" do you mean send "IOCTL_STORAGE_EJECT_MEDIA"? If so then am I correct that we do not need to remove PDO for devices such as disk drive (since it supports the notion of media ejection) and we need to remove PDO for devices such as USB stick (since it is itself "media")? Sorry if question is stupid.

Comment: @new_user - i mean user press `safely remove hardware` - in this case you not receiver any ioctl, but first your pdo received `IRP_MN_REMOVE_DEVICE`

Comment: @RbMmThank you. And what should we do if bus device object receives `IRP_MN_SURPRISE_REMOVAL` and children are still connected? Will they automatically receive `IRP_MN_REMOVE_DEVICE` or we should mark all of them and call `IoInvalidateDeviceRelations`?

Comment: @new_user - you receive  `IRP_MN_REMOVE_DEVICE` after `IRP_MN_SURPRISE_REMOVAL`. and you not need call `IoInvalidateDeviceRelations` in this case. you call it when(i assume you have virtual software device) user request inject or eject device. general rules for surprise removal https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/handling-an-irp-mn-surprise-removal-request removal -

Comment: Thank you, I missed this one: "After this IRP succeeds and all open handles to the device are closed, the PnP manager sends an `IRP_MN_REMOVE_DEVICE` request to the device stack." So by the time we receive `IRP_MN_REMOVE_DEVICE` there will be no children attached, since we initiate child removal when we close handle or when we `safely remove hardware`.